# Active Disk Partitioning

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, gparted, disk

I want to make a partition of my current disk as shown in the picture. I tried GParted but it's not working because the current partition is running. in fact, the buttons are not active to proceed. 
Please help to divide it.

[Disk view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1yKe.png)

Comment: Best to boot from a live USB image and do it from there.  Back up important data first in case of oops.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the partitions on a drive you boot from; the key symbols show it's locked. See http://gparted.org for details. Boot from a LiveUSB and then you can change things.